# Json.Net How to deserialize null as empty string?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, json.net

I have string property in my class_ for example

```
        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The Mobile value cannot exceed 40 characters. ")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

By some reason during Convert.Deserialize process I need to have empty string in this property instead on null in case this value is not setup in JSON object. 
How to do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [DefaultValue](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) attribute.

Decorate it as

```
[DataMember]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
[StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The Mobile value cannot exceed 40 characters. ")]
[DefaultValue("")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: It doesn't work by without, [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email",DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]

Comment: @cleric - thanks for the update. Yes, I missed that, its been a while, sorry.