# Add Multiple Contract Resolver in Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Blueprint for data structure:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json, I have the following configuration for Json serialization.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { 
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
};
```

Clearly that, this will print out:

```
{
    name: null
}
```

Now, I need to add another NullToEmptyStringResolver to the ContractResolver in JsonSerializerSettings, how can I achieve that which output as below:

```
{
    name: ""
}
```

- Please note that my NullToEmptyStringResolver is already written. But I need to add both NullToEmptyStringResolver and CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver to the Contract Resolver.

Comment: Please do not deface your post.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Json.Net does not allow more than one contract resolver at a time, so you will need a way to combine their behaviors.  I'm assuming that `NullToEmptyStringResolver` is a custom resolver which inherits from Json.Net's `DefaultContractResolver` class.  If so, one simple way to achieve your desired result is to make the `NullToEmptyStringResolver` inherit from `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` instead.

```
public class NullToEmptyStringResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    ...
}
```

If you don't like that approach, another idea is to add the camel casing behavior to your`NullToEmptyStringResolver`.  If you take a look at how `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` is implemented in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs), you'll see this is as simple as setting the `NamingStrategy` in the constructor (assuming you are using Json.Net 9.0.1 or later).  You can add this same code to the constructor of your`NullToEmptyStringResolver`.

```
public class NullToEmptyStringResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public NullToEmptyStringResolver() : base()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy
        {
            ProcessDictionaryKeys = true,
            OverrideSpecifiedNames = true
        };
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: is it possible to apply this resolver on model as attribute? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820249/keeping-contract-resolver-in-attribute

Comment: What about a [`CompositeContractResolver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49475473/235671)?

Answer (score 12):

I find it's a much better idea to create a composite-contract-resolver. This is what I use in my projects:

```
public class CompositeContractResolver : IContractResolver, IEnumerable<IContractResolver>
{
    private readonly IList<IContractResolver> _contractResolvers = new List<IContractResolver>();

    public JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        return
            _contractResolvers
                .Select(x => x.ResolveContract(type))
                .FirstOrDefault(Conditional.IsNotNull);
    }

    public void Add([NotNull] IContractResolver contractResolver)
    {
        if (contractResolver == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contractResolver));
        _contractResolvers.Add(contractResolver);
    }

    public IEnumerator<IContractResolver> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _contractResolvers.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I then use it like this:

```
Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CompositeContractResolver
    {
        new InterfaceContractResolver<ISomething>(),
        new DefaultContractResolver()
    }
}
```

where my custom contract-resolvers return a `null` contract so the composite one can fall through the default one if there is no match.

```
public class InterfaceContractResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public InterfaceContractResolver()
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsInterface) throw new InvalidOperationException("T must be an interface.");
    }

    public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        return 
            typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type) 
                ? base.ResolveContract(typeof(T)) 
                : default;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return
            typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                ? base.CreateProperties(typeof(T), memberSerialization)
                : default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I think the point of the question was to *combine* the behaviors of two contract resolvers somehow for the same type. One resolver provided lowercase property names, and the other converted a null value to an empty string.  In your design you are returning the first resolver that can resolve the contract for the given type. So if both contract resolvers can handle `string`, for example, then you would only get the behavior of one one of them--whichever one was first in the list.  In practice, there really isn't a good way to combine behaviors, because you can only return one contract.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it more, you might be able to do that using the Decorator pattern.  Food for thought anyway.

Comment: @BrianRogers oh, but I'm not sure this is really about combining behaviours... only one resolver can work at a time, each one with a different strategy so at some point you'll hit the right one... won't you?

Comment: It is true that Json.Net wasn't really designed for more than one contract resolver at a time, but the question wants the combined behaviors of two resolvers which were created for different purposes.  Say I have a string property called `FooBar` and I want it to be camel-cased (`fooBar`) in JSON.  I have a CamelCaseContractResolver to do that.  I also want the value to be represented as an empty string in JSON when it is null.  I have a separate contract resolver which does that.  So how would I get them to work together so that both handle the string?  That is the essence of the question.

Comment: @BrianRogers _I also want the value to be represented as an empty string in JSON when it is null._ I think a custom converter is a better choice for this purpose then a contract resolver. Turning a `null` into an empty string isn't a contract resolver's job... is it? It could also be achieved by perhaps a `DefaultValue` attribute. A contract resolver should really resolve only contracts and not manipulate property values... am I right? OP's approach is wrong.

Comment: You're right, but unfortunately converters are not called for null values (unless that has changed recently).  So you would handle it by using a contract resolver to apply a custom `IValueProvider` to string properties' contracts.

Comment: @BrianRogers well, I've tested it with a custom converter and it is called for `null` string properties and you can populate it with an empty string this way...

Comment: @t3chb0t what is `Conditional.IsNotNull` ?

Comment: I like your idea it's clean.

Comment: @Konrad it's one of my functional [extensions](https://github.com/he-dev/Reusable/blob/master/Reusable.Core/src/Extensions/Conditional.cs#L14) that I use to avoid writing `=> x != null` etc. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative.  Rather than using two ContractResolvers, you can use `NamingStrategy` instead of `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new NullToEmptyStringResolver(){NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()}
};
```

This is the similar @BrianRogers's second approach.  I just didn't hard code the setting to `NullToEmptyStringResolver` class.