# Convert empty strings to null with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm having trouble finding a way to automatically **deserialize** (server side) all `EmptyOrWhiteSpace` strings to `null` . Json.Net by default simply assigns the value to the object property, and I need to verify string by string whether it is empty or white space, and then set it to null.

I need this to be done upon deserialization, so I don't have to remember to verify every single string that comes from the client.

How can I override this on Json Net?

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm

Comment: @garfbradaz how does that solve his problem? That setting tells it how to handle null, not how to handle blank strings.

Comment: @garfbradaz I don't have null values that need to be handled, I have empty strings that need to be converted to null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23832417/961526 : you just need to invert the logic ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Works for serialization, but it doesn't work for deserialization

Comment: Did you modify the SetValue method also ?

Comment: Yep, both getvalue and setvalue are never even called when I send the json to my server

Comment: And (stupid question probably), you use these settings when calling the deserializer  ? Something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(myjsondata, settings);` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124913/discussion-between-victor-and-raphael-althaus).

Comment: Not sure why this is closed as unfocused? It's askign a clear single question - How do I configured Newtonsoft to deserialise EmptyString to Null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of source digging, I solved my problem.
Turns out all the solutions proposed in the comments only work if I am deserializing a complex object which contains a property that is a string.
In this case, yes, simply modifying the contract resolver works [1].

However, what I needed was a way to convert **any** string to null upon deserialization, and modifying the contract this way will fail for the case where my object is just a string, i.e.,

```
public void MyMethod(string jsonSomeInfo)
{
  // At this point, jsonSomeInfo is "\"\"",
  // an emmpty string.

  var deserialized = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize(new StringReader(jsonSomeInfo), typeof(string));

  // deserialized = "", event if I used the modified contract resolver [1].
}
```

What happens is that when we work with a complex object, internally JSON.NET assigns a `TokenType` of `JsonToken.StartObject` to the reader, which will cause the deserialization to follow a certain path where `property.ValueProvider.SetValue(target, value);` is called.

However, if the object is just a string, the `TokenType` will be `JsonToken.String`, and the path will be different, and the value provider will never be invoked.

In any event, my solution was to build a custom converter to convert `JsonReader`s that have `TokenType == JsonToken.String` (code below).

**Solution**

```
public class StringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
            if (reader.Value == null) return null;

            string text = reader.Value.ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return text;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not needed because this converter cannot write json");
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

[1] Credits to @Raphaël Althaus.

```
public class NullToEmptyStringResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return type.GetProperties()
        .Select(p => {
            var jp = base.CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization);
            jp.ValueProvider = new EmptyToNullStringValueProvider(p);
            return jp;
        }).ToList();
    }
}

public class EmptyToNullStringValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    PropertyInfo _MemberInfo;

    public EmptyToNullStringValueProvider(PropertyInfo memberInfo)
    {
        _MemberInfo = memberInfo;
    }

    public object GetValue(object target)
    {
        object result = _MemberInfo.GetValue(target);

        if (_MemberInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string) && result != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.ToString()))
        {
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void SetValue(object target, object value)
    {
        if (_MemberInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string) && value != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            value = null;
        }

        _MemberInfo.SetValue(target, value);
    }
}
```