# JsonSerializationException while parsing JSON to DataTable

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, datatable, json.net

I am trying to parse JSON data to a `DataTable` in C#. But while parsing I am seeing a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`.

> Error converting value "" to type 'System.DateTime'. Path '[1]['Created Date']', line 8, position 20.

Here is the code which I used to parse the data:

```
DataTable dtData = JArray.Parse(jsonString).ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Sample JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "rno": 1,
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Created Date": "2014-04-30T14:39:12.2397769Z"
  },
  {
    "rno": 2,
    "Name": "ABC",
    "Created Date": ""
  }
]
```

Can someone tell me how to manage this type of scenario. I just want to prevent a data type change while adding data into the data table. Instead of `DateTime`, the  column data type should be set as string.

Comment: If you take a look at the value of ```created date``` in the second entry, do you notice anything?

Comment: Also, take a step back and explain why you want to convert JSON to a `DataTable`. That is odd. Wouldn't you rather it be converted into a list of a concrete type? Why _specifically_ do you want `DataTable`?

Comment: Do `DataTable` support `Nullable<T>` @Eldar?

Comment: Well if you can't control JSON data itself you can try the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862088/12354911). Which converts empty strings into null values in the JSON string.

Comment: @mjwills I'm calling third party library's function, which only support data in the DataTable format. Due to this I don't have any alternative way to parse data.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for your attention. Yes! I got the root cause of it. But can't able to fund any solution to prevent error.

Comment: @Eldar Thanks for providing link but may be it's impact on performance as it's traverse each data. And our JSON data contain minimum 10K records.

Comment: Use https://app.quicktype.io?share=wq0HmxtiEUoJoDaIEOmQ to parse it into standard C# types. Then generate the `DataTable` manually and populate it manually.

Comment: Your problem is that the `"Created Date"` is being recognized as a DateTime string -- but `""` is not a valid DateTime string.  To disable automatic `DateTime` recognition, set `DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None` as shown in [Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11856694/3744182).  now your `DataTable` will be created with a `string` column rather than a `DateTime` column.  You can postprocess it after deserialization to convert the column to `DateTime` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When deserializing JSON to a `DataTable`, Json.Net automatically tries to determine the data type of each column based on the property values of the first item in the array.  In this case, the first item has a date string for the `Created Date` property, so that column's data type is being set to `DateTime`.  The error occurs on the second item when the parser encounters an empty string for the `Created Date` property.  An empty string cannot be converted to a `DateTime`, so that results in a `JsonSerializationException`.

If you want the `Created Date` column to always be parsed as a string instead of a `DateTime`, you can set `DateParseHandling` to `None`.  That will prevent the error you are seeing.

Change this code:

```
DataTable dtData = JArray.Parse(jsonString).ToObject<DataTable>();
```

To this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None };
DataTable dtData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString, settings);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EWWGT0

Comment: This doesnt work in .net 6 with the latest newtonsoft Json.Net package

Comment: @PBo I beg to differ.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Etwl4Q

Comment: You are right Brian Rogers - While we updated to .net 6 we did not update the nuget packages. the newtonsoft version we had was 9.0.0 which suddenly stopped working and I wrote some work around code for that. Once I saw your comment, I discovered we are not using the latest version of newtonsoft json.net package. once we upgraded to the latest version, I reverted what I did and it worked. Quite unexpected. I wish I had the time to figure out why it happened