# c# convert class to json file

Tags: c#, json

I'm using this class:

```
 class message
    {
        public content Content { get; set; }
        public from From { get; set;  }
        public personalizations Personalizations { get; set; }
    }

   
    public class content
    {
        public string type = "text/html";
        public string value = "html";
    }

    public class from
    {
        public string email = "example@example.com";
        public string name = "example";

    }
    public class personalizations
    {
        public List<to> tos { get; set; }
    }
    public class to
    {
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm serializing the class **Message** to:

```
    var msg = new message() { Content = new content() { type = "text/html", value = "html" },
        From = new from() { email = "example@example.com", name = "example" },
        Personalizations = new personalizations() { tos = new List<to>() { new to(), new to() } } };
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);
```

I'm trying to get an array of every parent.
The JSON output format is:

```
{
  "Content": {
   
     "type": "text/html",
    "value": "html"
  },
  "From": {
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "name": "example"
   },
  "Personalizations": 
   {
    "tos": [
      {
        "subject": null,
        "email": null
      },
      {
        "subject": null,
        "email": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but I do want this format instead:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text/html", 
      "value": "Html"
    }
  ], 
  "from": {
    "email": "", 
    "name": ""
  }, 

  "personalizations": [
    {
      "subject": "",
      "to": [ { "email": "" }]
    },
    {
        "subject": "",
        "to": [{ "email": "" }]
    },
    {
        "subject": "",
        "to": [{ "email": "" }]
    }
    
    ]

}
```

How can I manage to do change the format to the last one?

thanks in advance

EDIT:

I want to change the format not the values

example:

in the last JSON example I have a object of personalization which holds multiple JSON objects, but in the first one I only have an object.

Comment: `null != ""`....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830206/json-convert-empty-string-instead-of-null

Comment: @shurik you are right... Obviously OP knows how to construct classes from JSON, and how to represent object as single element array - reopened and waiting for clarification on what they have problem with exactly.

Comment: Is it the NULL he's trying to handle, or is it the structure of the JSON itself? "Personalizations" has a different structure in the two examples.

Comment: @shurik no i'm not talking about the values but about the format

Comment: @RobertPaulsen no , its not about the values , i'm just trying to make the same json format from the first one to the last one

Comment: Did you try to change your object composition, so it is represented as you expect. ie: list of content instead of content?

Answer (score 2):

You can take the JSON you want to end up with and copy it to your clipboard. You can then go to any .cs file in Visual Studio from the Edit menu you can expand the "Paste Special" menu. Choose the option "Paste JSON as classes" and you get this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Content[] content { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public Personalization[] personalizations { get; set; }
}

public class From
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Personalization
{
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public To[] to { get; set; }
}

public class To
{
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your latest comment, you want to change the output format. You can achieve that by moving the property "public string subject" from the "to" class to "personalizations" class, like here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/40nBnl

You should, by the way, take a look at [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)