# JSONConvert converts null array into double quotes empty string

Tags: c#, json

I am not able to serialize the following property correctly

pubic string[] names {get;set;}

Many times names array is null and at the time of serialization it is coming as "names":[""]

```
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Requestobj, settings);
```

How  can I change from `"names" : [""] to "names" : []`

Comment: Looks like your array isn't empty, it has a single, empty string in it. How are you setting the names property?

Comment: You should be able to reverse this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830206/json-convert-empty-string-instead-of-null/23832417#23832417

Answer (score 1):

just simple string replacing will help you

```
json=json.Replace("[\"\"]","[]");
```

But it is better to fix the API if you have an access. The API problem is that it doesn't create an empty array, it creates an array with a single, empty string in it.

```
var test = new { names = new string[] {""}};
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test); // {"names":[""]}

var test = new { names = new string[] {}};
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test); // {"names":[]}
```