# JsonTextWriter serializes null to "null" using ToString()

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using JSON.NET's JsonTextWriter as follows:

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
var textWriter = (TextWriter)writer;
var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter);

jsonTextWriter.WriteNull();

var data = jsonTextWriter.ToString();
```

How can I achieve that data will be empty string instead of `"null"`?

Comment: Your example has an error; you're assigning the type name of the `jsonTextWriter` to `data` instead of using the `StringWriter`

Comment: Don't call `WriteNull` if you don't want to write `null`? You're directly causing this.

Comment: You could consider using inbuilt attributes in Json.Net, to achieve the same, check out, 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15136173/1559611

Comment: @usr Yes, you are right :) I was missing something in my project so I asked this question, that is no longer valid for me now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the `JsonTextWriter` in this instance is correct; to represent a null value in JSON, the expected token is `null`.  For example:

```
{
    "Name"    : "SomeGuy",
    "Address" : null
}
```

From your question, it seems that what you're looking to do is write an actual empty string to indicate a complete lack of value.  You could do that by calling `jsonTextWriter.WriteRaw("")`.  However, that will produce invalid JSON, as you'd end up with:

```
{
    "Name"    : "SomeGuy",
    "Address" : 
}
```

I'm guessing that isn't want you want, either.  To emit an empty string that actually represents an empty string value in JSON, you'll want to do `jsonTextWriter.WriteValue("")`  That will produce the expected `""` token that I believe you are looking for, which would look like:

```
{
    "Name"    : "SomeGuy",
    "Address" : ""
}
```

As a full example, to emit the object that I've been using would be something like:

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
var textWriter = (TextWriter)writer;
var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter);

jsonTextWriter.WriteStartObject();
jsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName("Name");
jsonTextWriter.WriteValue("SomeGuy");
jsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName("Address");
jsonTextWriter.WriteValue("");
jsonTextWriter.WriteEndObject();

var data = writer.ToString();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This behavior is correct. I was missing something so this whole question is no longer valid for me.